# Crear input dinámico con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar.
Quiero crear una lista para comprar productos, esta lista debe tener los siguientes campos

- Producto
- Cantidad
- Costo
- Total

Pero la dinámica consiste en lo siguiente.

Como pueden ver en este código la lista se debe agregar de manera dinámica, se pueden agregar varios pedidos a la vez.

En la ventana modal buscar el producto y luego al darle aceptar quiero que se cree automáticamente la fila con los campos que se ve en el código para que el usuario pueda llenaros.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" disabled value="Vaso"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" value="3"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" value="10"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" value="30" disabled></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remover</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="producto">Buscar Producto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // Refresca Producto: Refresco la Lista de Productos dentro de la Tabla
  // Si es vacia deshabilito el boton guardar para obligar a seleccionar al menos un producto al usuario
  // Sino habilito el boton Guardar para que pueda Guardar
    function RefrescaProducto(){
        var ip = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('#guardar').attr('disabled','disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
        $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
            i++;
            ip.push({ id_pro : $(this).val() });
        });
        // Si la lista de Productos no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
        if (i > 0) {
            $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        var ipt=JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
        $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
    }
       function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text();//Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select
           
            
            var sptext = text.split();
            
            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td> <input  class="form-control" id="1" name="precio" value="23" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control" id="2" name="cantidad" value="2" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control"  id="3" name="total" value="46" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';
            
            $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected
            
            RefrescaProducto();//Refresco Productos
                
            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300); 
                RefrescaProducto();
            });        
           $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
           });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
    <from>
        <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
          <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />
        <table id="TablaPro" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="ProSelected"><!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
                <tr>
             
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<!--Agregue un boton en caso de desear enviar los productos para ser procesados-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="guardar" name= "guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Guardar</button>
                </div>
    </from>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Producto</label>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%' >
                                        <option value="Lentes">Lentes</option>
                                        <option value="Casco">Casco</option>
                                        <option value="Gorra">Gorra</option>
                                </select>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                        <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Si deseas recibir esta Lista de Productos en un controlador ve lo siguiente:

```
    var ipt=JSON.stringify(ip);
    $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));//Convierto los Productos a un JSON Para mandarlo al controlador por POST
```

Entonces al presionar guardar , deberías poder enviar los valores por POST , a través del FORM, de manera que en tu form deberias tener algo asi:

```
  <form action="llamada al controlador: miControlador" role="form" method="post">
```

En tu controlador debes poder decodificar del JSON todos estos productos, para hacerlo debes tener un controlador que realice algo así:

```
 public function miControlador(){
          $data = array();
          foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  //Recibo el los valores por POST 
            $data[$key] = $value;  
         }

         $acturl = urldecode($data['ListaPro']); //decodifico el JSON
         $productos = json_decode($acturl);

        foreach ($productos  as $pro) {
            $misProductos = array(
                'cantidad' => $pro->cantidad,
                'productoId' => $pro->id_pro,//así llamamos al id del producto en la vista en la funcion RefrescaProducto
                'precio' => $pro->precio,
                'total' =>$pro->total        
            );
     //Guardar en Base de Datos
 }
```

Luego tendrías tus productos en un Array, y puedes manejarlos como desees, no e usado Laravel pero de esta forma que te planteo es como normalmente lo hago. Espero te Sirva. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Samuel Heredia.

Comment: De nada cualquier duda, coméntame y te ayudo.

Comment: Me funciona de maravilla, lo siento si estoy siendo muy molestosa, pero como puedo recibir todo en mi controlador?, estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Edite la respuesta agregando lo que me pediste, espero te ayude, no he usado Laravel pero en teoría debe ser algo similar a lo que te planteo, espero haberme explicado. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Al tbody le asigno un id, asi como al boton agregar

```
....
....    
<tbody id="productos">
</tbody>
.....
.....
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="agregarProducto">Agregar</button>
```

JQuery, 
Al dar click en el boton agregar envio (realizo un peticion ajax) el id del producto para buscar dicho producto el cual lo recibe un archivo php y ese archivo php me devuelve una respuesta el cual anexo dentro de tbody

```
    $( "#agregarProducto" ).click(function() {
        var getId = $("#producto").val();
        $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "BuscarProducto.php",
              data: { id: getId }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
          $("#productos").html(msg);
      });
    });
```

BuscarProducto

```
<?php
    $mysqli=new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test');
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $q=$mysqli->query("select * from test");
    while($r=$q->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>miinfo</td><td>miinfo</td><td>miinfo</td><td>miinfo</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

He tomado como ejemplo el script que aquí se comparte y le he hecho modificaciones en las variables, pero, quiero que al cargar en el  desde el SELECT el nombre del servicio, también cargue el costo del mismo. Ejemplo; Al seleccionar Revisión también cargue el costo de la revisión el el tbody. Podrían ayudarme en eso por favor.
Este es el script que tengo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Refresca Servicio: Refresco la Lista de servicios dentro de la Tabla
    // Si es vacia deshabilito el boton guardar para obligar a seleccionar al menos un servicio al usuario
    // Sino habilito el boton Guardar para que pueda Guardar
    function RefrescaServicio(){
        var ip = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('#guardar').attr('disabled','disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
        $('.iServicio').each(function(index, element) {
        i++;
        ip.push({ id_pro : $(this).val() });
        });
        // Si la lista de servicios no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
        if (i > 0) {
        $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        var ipt=JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de servicios a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
        $('#ListaServ').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
    }
    function agregaServicio() {
        var sel = $('#id_serv').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del servicio
        var text = $('#id_serv').find(':selected').text();//Capturo el Nombre del servicio- Texto dentro del Select
        var sptext = text.split();

        var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
        newtr = newtr + '<td class="iServicio" >' + sel + '</td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td> <input class="form-control" id="1" name="cantidad" required /></td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" id="2" name="precio" required /></td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control"  id="3" name="total"  required /></td>';
        newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

        $('#ServSeleccionado').append(newtr); //Agrego el servicio al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

        RefrescaServicio();//Refresco Servicios

        $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
            if ($('#ServSeleccionado tr.item').length == 0)
            $('#ServSeleccionado .no-item').slideDown(300);
            RefrescaServicio();
        });
        $('.iServicio').off().change(function(e) {
            RefrescaServicio();
        });
      }
</script>
```

Quiero que el resultado sea este:
[image: Deseo que el resultado sea este]

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta sino una pregunta distinta. Revisa el [tour] y la sección [ask] para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Hola Franklin. como te dice @blonfu, has de hacer una pregunta nueva y no usar la seccion de Respuestas. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que usar etiquetas jquery en los input para poder llevarte la información por ajax , tambien consultarla, y poder crearla en el modal, el modal es codigo html tratalo de igual manera ideal si esta en css puro o jquery, importante que este rendereada la información en json para que sea escalable y los tiempos de uso de memoria  sean de manera asyncrona obtiendo un mejor tiempo de carga.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ¿Me podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo?