# ordenes de salida insertar varios insumos y enviar al controlador LARAVEL

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito un poco de ayuda con esto, soy un poco nuevo en laravel y js, lo que quiero lograr es insertar varios Insumos(productos) a una orden de salida(o detalle) y enviarlo al controlador.
Tengo el js para insertar varios registros de insumos (que lo encontre en este mismo sitio) que me funciona perfectamente. lo que no puedo lograr es decodificar el JSON(ya que el código cuenta con envio por JSON) para enviarlo al controlador y procesarlo para guardarlo en la base de datos.

estoy utilizando esta solución pero no logro procesarlos en el controlador: [Crear input dinámico con jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58006/crear-input-din%C3%A1mico-con-jquery?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // Refresca Producto: Refresco la Lista de Productos dentro de la Tabla
  // Si es vacia deshabilito el boton guardar para obligar a seleccionar al menos un producto al usuario
  // Sino habilito el boton Guardar para que pueda Guardar
    function RefrescaProducto(){
        var ip = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('#guardar').attr('disabled','disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
        $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
            i++;
            ip.push({ id_pro : $(this).val() });
        });
        // Si la lista de Productos no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
        if (i > 0) {
            $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
        }
        var ipt=JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
        $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
    }
       function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text();//Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select


            var sptext = text.split();

            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="' +sel+'" >';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + text + '</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control col-sm-1" id="1" name="cantidad" type="text" value="" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

            $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

            RefrescaProducto();//Refresco Productos

            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300); 
                RefrescaProducto();
            });        
           $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
           });
    }
</script>

  <div class="container col-sm-offset-3 " >
    <h3>Agregar insumos</h3>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
      <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />

    <table id="TablaPro" class="table col-sm-9" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Insumo</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>

                <th>Acción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="ProSelected"><!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Insumo a la lista</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Insumos</label>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%' >
                                   @foreach($newinsumos as $newinsumo)
                                    <option value="{{$newinsumo->id}}">{{$newinsumo->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                            </select>
            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                    <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

controlador:

```
      $data = array();
      foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  //Recibo el los valores por POST 
        $data[$key] = $value;  
     }

     //dd($data);

      $acturl = urldecode($data['ListaPro']); //decodifico el JSON
      $productos = json_decode($acturl,true);

    foreach ($productos  as $pro) {

         $misProductos = array(
            'cantidad' => $pro->cantidad,
            'insumo_id' => $pro->id_pro,//así llamamos al id del producto en la vista en la funcion RefrescaProducto      
        );
}
```

print_r($productos);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_pro] => ) )
```

Error:

```
ErrorException in OrdenSalidaController.php line 74:
Trying to get property of non-object
```

dd($productos);

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "id_pro" => ""
  ]
]
```

dd($data);

```
    array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "htxTHiVFO7totwCWcnYBMjaEArlBsD99prqueEBo"
  "url" => "http://localhost:8888/insumos/desarrollo/public/admin/orden_salidas"
  "id" => "0"
  "page" => "1"
  "fecha_ingreso" => "2018-01-10"
  "responsable" => "Rodrigo Ortiz"
  "establecimiento" => "3"
  "detalle" => "44"
  "_wysihtml5_mode" => "1"
  "ListaPro" => "%5B%7B%22id_pro%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22id_pro%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D"
  "cantidad" => "3"
  "pro_id" => "5"
]
```

pd: si agrego mas de un insumo a la orden de salida solo me trae, como pueden ver con el dd($data) el ultimo insumo ? como puedo solucionar esto?.

Ojala me puedan ayudar, intente ser lo mas claro posible. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro de haber entendido tu pregunta , quieres enviar los datos al controlador en formato JSON pero lo estas enviado por ajax o es un formulario POST? comprobaste con un console.log o depurando que en javascript el JSON tenga un formato correcto ? en el controlador usas las variables de php $_POST no se si sabes que existe un objeto [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests) en laravel que te facilita la obtención de los datos en las llamadas, con lo que veo en tu codigo por ahora te puedo decir que compruebes que el JSON en javascript esta enviándose con el formato correcto y si lo envias por un AJAX asegurate de que le estas pasando dataType: "json" en las opciones.
Un saludo